# Matplotlib: Include certain points during animation

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I wanted to simulate the trajectory of a projectile which is fired from a certain position and show the highest point and the position where it hits the ground during the animation. My problem is that I can´t figure out how to add these points dynamically while the animation takes place.

Here´s how I animate the path:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import animation, rc
from IPython.display import HTML


# First set up the figure, the axis, and the plot element we want to animate:
## Get Figure and Axes to plot in
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

## Limits the x- and y-axis
ax.set_xlim((0, 30))
ax.set_ylim((0, 25))

 line, = ax.plot([], [], lw=2)

# Setup interval for plotting
interval = np.linspace(0, 29.43, 100)

# Defines the path function of the projectile
def path_of_projectile(x):
    return (-(x - 9.81)**2 / 19.62) + 19.62

# Defines the highest point of the projectile
def get_highest_point(x):
    return 14.715 + 9.81 * x - 4.905 * (1)**2

# Define the initialization function, which plots the background of each frame:
def init():
    line.set_data([], [])
    return (line,)

y = path_of_projectile((interval))
# Define the animation function, which is called for each new frame:
def animate(i):
    line.set_data(interval[0:i], y[0:i])
    return (line,)


# Compile the animation
anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, init_func=init,
                               frames=100, interval=20, 
                               blit=True)
# Plot it
HTML(anim.to_jshtml())
```

The function **get_highest_point** returns the highest point of the projectile f.e. How can I include it to show up during the animation?

Comment: Are the highest point of the function and the maximum value of y the same? I don't understand the relationship between them at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I also commented, I don't understand the relationship between the function to get the highest point and the Y-value; by indicating the highest point of the Y-value as a point, I think the same technique can be used to handle the highest point obtained from the function. The point is that since the highest point is known before drawing, only the same value as the highest point should be drawn on the graph.

```
def animate(i):
    line.set_data(interval[0:i], y[0:i])
    if y[i] == max(y):
        ax.scatter(interval[i], y[i], s=25, color='r')
    return (line,)
```

[image]